# DirectShow to RTSP to Kurento

Tags: streaming, webrtc, directshow, rtsp, kurento

I need to broadcast a DirectShow samples to Kurento using RTSP. Is there a good way to send RTSP from DirectShow?

So far I have tested with raw samples to HTTP endpoint, different leadtools solutions RTSP, Dash. But no luck so far!

Comment: This is LEADTOOLS support. You haven't specified which of our modules or classes you tried or how. If you haven't contacted us regarding this, please reach out using our email or online chat support services (both are free) and provide more details about your requirements, and we will see if our SDK's features can help you do what you need.

Comment: How can i contact you to give further details?

Comment: You could use the [online chat service](https://www.leadtools.com/support/chat) during working hours. You could also email support@leadtools.com, where we usually reply the same working day or the following day.